# LinearRegression predicting providing multiple features as a list

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, linear-regression

I'm using simple LinearRegression() to predict next day's closing price. I know it's not reliable but at least I'm trying to understand and training on LR.

I simply provide most recent `open, high, low, close` values as feature. What I really want to do is to provide last 10 day's `open, high, low, close` prices. Below you can find what i did so far:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.metrics import mean_squared_error, mean_absolute_error, median_absolute_error
pd.options.mode.chained_assignment = None

sym = "EURUSD"
period = "1d"
fl = "./feed/{} {}.csv".format(period, sym)
dg = 0.0001 # pip digits

df = pd.read_csv(fl)
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'])
df['NextClose'] = df['Close'].shift(-1)
cols = ['Open', 'High', 'Low', 'Close'] # features
prd_cols = ['NextClose'] # prediction
real_prd = df[cols].iloc[-1:] # predict this after training
hour = df['Date'].iloc[-1]
df.dropna(inplace=True)

test_p = 20 # percent of test size
total = len(df) # total in DataFrame
test_size = int(total * test_p / 100)
X = df[cols]
y = df[prd_cols]
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, shuffle=True)

lr = LinearRegression()
lr.fit(X_train, y_train)
y_pred = lr.predict(X_test)
mse = mean_squared_error(y_test, y_pred)
rmse = int(np.sqrt(mse) / dg)
mae = int(mean_absolute_error(y_test, y_pred) / dg)
print("")
print("Pair:", sym, "Time:", period, hour)
print("Mean Sq. Err: {:.10f}".format(mse))
print("Root Mean Sq. Err:", rmse, "pips")
print("Mean Abs. Err:", mae, "pips")
print("Score: {:.2f}%".format(np.round(lr.score(X_test, y_test) * 100, 2)))
# predict last value
real_pred = lr.predict(real_prd)
print("Prediction:", np.round(real_pred[0][0], 5))

plt.scatter(y_pred, y_test)
plt.show()
```

**EDIT**
**Output:**

```
Pair: EURUSD Time: 1d 2019-02-28 00:00:00
Mean Sq. Err: 0.0000594541
Root Mean Sq. Err: 77 pips
Mean Abs. Err: 56 pips
Score: 99.78%
Prediction: 1.14154
```

SAMPLE Source:

```
         Open     High      Low    Close
4921  1.14087  1.14092  1.13610  1.13658
4922  1.13658  1.13678  1.13245  1.13383
4923  1.13385  1.13509  1.13213  1.13222
4924  1.13199  1.13251  1.13189  1.13241
4925  1.13243  1.13303  1.12675  1.12787
4926  1.12785  1.13397  1.12580  1.13340
4927  1.13336  1.13417  1.12495  1.12648
4928  1.12650  1.13099  1.12501  1.12950
4929  1.12950  1.13064  1.12343  1.12922
4930  1.12916  1.12960  1.12898  1.12952
4931  1.12950  1.13341  1.12940  1.13118
4932  1.13116  1.13576  1.12757  1.13401
4933  1.13399  1.13714  1.13251  1.13464
4934  1.13465  1.13665  1.13208  1.13400
4935  1.13399  1.13558  1.13163  1.13331
4936  1.13362  1.13424  1.13292  1.13424
4937  1.13420  1.13677  1.13369  1.13651
4938  1.13651  1.14028  1.13454  1.13931
4939  1.13936  1.14037  1.13624  1.13799
4940  1.13793  1.14198  1.13675  1.14116
```

**PLOT:**
[image]

How can i deploy last 10 rows as a feature and still get one result?

Comment: Please post a sample of your data, and explain further your question (what does "deploy" mean here?); also, including a whole bunch of `print` and `plot` statements in the code without their outputs is arguably not helpful in addressing the essence of your question and just creates clutter...

Comment: Edited the question with sample data, plot and output

Answer (score 0):

I have coded the following solution

```
cols = []
for i in range(1, 11):
    cl = "Open_{}".format(i)
    cols.append(cl)
    df[cl] = df['Open'].shift(i)
    cl = "High_{}".format(i)
    cols.append(cl)
    df[cl] = df['High'].shift(i)
    cl = "Low_{}".format(i)
    cols.append(cl)
    df[cl] = df['Low'].shift(i)
    cl = "Close_{}".format(i)
    cols.append(cl)
    df[cl] = df['Close'].shift(i)
```